# I need help converting a time formatted as H:mm:ss AM/PM to H:mm AM/PM in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript">

var current_time = new Date();
current_time     = current_time.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');

</script>
```

This code returns H:mm:ss AM/PM with the help of the regular expression that I found on a previous post.

I want H:mm AM/PM.

The problem started with IE 11.  I didn't have this problem with IE 10.

Any suggestions?

TIA.

Comment: See the Remarks regarding IE11 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/474de325(v=vs.94).aspx . I don't have a direct solution but hope that helps. A shot in the dark is to try `current_time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US").replace(/:\d+ /, ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for your issue is to use the [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library. The minified version is only 8.9kb. Your current code then becomes:

```
var current_time = moment().format("h:mm A");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var current_date = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString("en-US").replace(/:\d{1,2} /, ' ');
```